# xml:id of ancestor element

Tags: xslt, tei

My stylesheet used `version="3.0"`. My engine version Saxon PEE 9.9.1.7.

The `xml:id` attribute of `w` is built from `xml:id` of `l` + `'_'` + the `text()` value of `w`. It seems to me that the `xpath` of `xml:id` of `l` is correct, but this doesn't work.
Example of `xml` before transformation:

```
<div3 xml:id="ktu1-1_ii">
   <!-- tei elements div4 and lg -->
         <l n="1a">
            <!-- other children -->
            <w>l</w>
         </l>
```

Processing instructions:

```
   <xsl:template match="div3/div4/lg/l">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:if test="not(@xml:id)">
            <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::div3/@xml:id, '_l', @n)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
 
   <xsl:template match="l/w">
      <xsl:variable name="xmlid">
         <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::l/@xml:id"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:message select="$xmlid"/> <!-- test @xml:id, nothing -->
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:attribute name="pos"></xsl:attribute>
         <!-- Calculate xml:id based on parent 'l' xml:id -->
         <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(ancestor::l/@xml:id, ' ', '')) || '_' || replace(., '\s|̊', '')"/> 
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

The result is correct for `l`: `<l n='1a' xml:id='ktu1-1_ii_l1a'>`, but only one part works for `w` `<w xml:id="_l">l</w>` when the result should be `<w xml:id="ktu1-1_ii_l1a_l">l</w>`.

Any idea where the error might have come from?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. Knowing that `xml:id` of `w` depends on `xml:id`of `l`, the first part of `xml:id` of `w` will automatically be empty. Is there any way of saying that a first transformation must first consider `l`, a second transformation `w`?

Comment: In fact, I have made a test with:`<xsl:variable name="n1"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::l/@n"/></xsl:variable> <xsl:message select="$n1"/>` and it works. `@n` of element `l` is always manually added. This is why I have come to the conclusion set out above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following (simplified) example:

**XML**

```
<div3 xml:id="ktu1-1_ii">
    <!-- tei elements div4 and lg -->
    <l n="1a">
        <!-- other children -->
        <w>l</w>
        <w>l</w>
    </l>
</div3>
```

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
<xsl:template match="l[not(@xml:id)]">
    <xsl:variable name="l_id" select="concat(ancestor::div3/@xml:id, '_l', @n)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="xml:id" select="$l_id"/>   
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="l_id" select="$l_id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w">
    <xsl:param name="l_id"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="xml:id" select="concat($l_id, '_', position())"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div3 xml:id="ktu1-1_ii"><!-- tei elements div4 and lg -->
   <l n="1a" xml:id="ktu1-1_ii_l1a"><!-- other children -->
      <w xml:id="ktu1-1_ii_l1a_2">l</w>
      <w xml:id="ktu1-1_ii_l1a_3">l</w>
   </l>
</div3>
```

Here the value of the `l` parent's `xml:id` is calculated **once** and passed down to the children as a [parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#parameters-to-template-rules).

---

P.S. The purpose of this exercise is not entirely clear. If you need to have a unique ID for each node, you could simply have your stylesheet [generate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-generate-id) them instead of trying to assemble them piecemeal from their ancestor parts.

Comment: Thank you @michael. Although your code is more concise, the `@correspUnic` attribute has disappeared. In fact, there is a Unicode/Ugaritic [concordance table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76979618/4540261) before the generic templates, in this specific case, `l` and `w`. In the option I had chosen, this worked perfectly. Any suggestions to achieve the same with your proposal? For example, for `<w>bt</w>`, I should have `<w xml:id="ktu1-1_ii_l0_bt" correspUnic="&#66433;&#66458;>bt</w>` --I have removed `position()` which I don't need and replace by `normalize-space(replace(., '\s|̊', ''))`

Comment: I am afraid I have no clue what you refer to. There is no `correspUnic` in the input example, nor do I see one being created in your code. Of course, you *could* add one as discussed in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971874/automatically-add-an-attribute-and-values-based-on-latinized-characters-between). But it has nothing to do with the problem you presented on this page.

Comment: Of course, you are right! Anyway, I found the solution that I will provide nevertheless. This may be helpful for others who encounter the same issue as I did: `<xsl:template match="l/w">…<xsl:if test="not(@xml:id) "><xsl:attribute name="xml:id" select="concat($l_id, '_', normalize-space(replace(., '\s|̊', '')))"/></xsl:if><xsl:if test="not(child::*) and (not(@correspUnic) or string-length(normalize-space(@correspUnic)) = 0)"><xsl:attribute name="correspUnic"><xsl:apply-templates select="text()" mode="map"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>…` So now my `xsl` transformation is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake you are making is to imagine that `ancestor::l/@xml:id` will access the value of `@xml:id` on the `l` element in the result tree, whereas it will actually access the value of `@xml:id` on the `l` element in the source tree.

To access the new value of `ancestor::l/@xml:id`, some of the options are:

1. Introduce a second phase of transformation, where the result of the first phase is captured in a variable and then subjected to a second transformation.
2. Recompute the value when needed, by moving the computation into a function and calling it from multiple places.
3. Make that function into a memo function so when you call it more than once on the same node, the previous value is remembered.

Comment: 4. Calculate the 1st ID in a variable and pass it as a parameter to the other template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A bit complicated at my level. I tried first to introduce a variable. To test if it works, I used the message statement, but it looks like I must have made an error as no value appears: before the templates, I added  `<xsl:variable name="result-of-first-phase"><xsl:apply-templates select="div3/div4/lg/l"/></xsl:variable>` and then `<xsl:template match="div3/div4/lg/l">` with no modification and then in the `l/w`template, I insert `<xsl:variable name="xmlid"><xsl:value-of select="$result-of-first-phase/ancestor::div3/@xml:id"/></xsl:variable>`

Comment: I have also tried another option following your last suggestion in `l` template by including `<xsl:apply-templates select="l/w"><xsl:with-param name="l-xmlid" select="@xml:id"/></xsl:apply-templates>` and then in `w` template `<xsl:param name="l-xmlid"/>`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Vanessa, pass the value you compute (e.g. `concat(ancestor::div3/@xml:id, '_l', @n)` down to the other templates. Trying to pass `@xml:id` of the `l` element which in the input doesn't have any attribute will not work as you only create that attribute for the result.

Comment: @Martin: I should have thought of that!!! It makes so much sense...and is so straightforward. Thank you so so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen), here is the correct `xsl`:

```
<xsl:template match="div3/div4/lg/l">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:if test="not(@xml:id)">
            <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::div3/@xml:id, '_l', @n)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
   
   <xsl:template match="l/w">
      <xsl:variable name="xmlid">
         <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::l/@xml:id"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:attribute name="pos"></xsl:attribute>
         <!-- Calculate xml:id based on parent 'l' xml:id, @n, and text() value of the current element -->
         <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::div3/@xml:id, '_l', ancestor::l/@n, '_', normalize-space(replace(., '\s|̊', '')))"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<l n='1a' xml:id='ktu1-1_ii_l1a'>
<!-- other children -->
<w xml:id="ktu1-1_ii_l1a_l">l</w>
</l>
```

Additional clarification added after receiving [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035008/4540261):

The current solution--which was my previous choice--is, from my point of view, likely more easily understandable, especially for `xsl` neophytes while Michael's suggestion is more concise and avoids repetition of the `xpath` with the addition of the variable `<xsl:variable name="l_id" select="concat(ancestor::div3/@xml:id, '_l', @n)"/>` in `l` and the parameter `<xsl:with-param name="l_id" select="$l_id"/>`--although I made a few adjustments considering my entire transformation file.

Comment: And what if there are two (or more) `w`elements  with the same content?

Comment: It works with several `w` elements. Anyway, I took your suggestion which is much more concise with a few adjustments.